# Капча на битрикс

Tags: битрикс, recaptcha

**Добрый день.**

Пытаюсь поставить на сайт ( bitrix ) капчу через маркетплейс, 
модуль называется: ***" reCaptchaFree "***,
но после установки и настройки модуля ( через установки ключа и секретного ключа ) [image: Ошибка капчи]


Выпрыгивает alert. 
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой? 
Если нет, то подскажите пожалуйста решение без маркетплейс.

**P.S:**

**Код и секретный код верный.**

Comment: это вы хотите стандартную капчу гугла?

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера и заскриньте ошибки оттуда.

Comment: Oleksandr, reCAPTCHA